# Is there any way to receive simple json with $.ajax jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

How can I receive data from another domain assuming it returns simple JSON not JSONP result?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "https://example.com",
    data : {
        key1 : "value1"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod"
});
```

The problem is that the server returns only JSON and there is no other option.
The host doesn't support CORS.

--

The answer is no way using jQuery ajax method.

To get all this stuff working the server has to wrap JSON response into some callback function.

For example assuming server side language is PHP:

```
...
$response = ['key' => 'value'];    
echo 'callback(' . json_encode($response) . ')';
```

Only in that case you will be able to receive JSON in $.ajax success callback.

If the server you request for doesn't support this feature you should search some other ways to do it.

Comment: [`$.getJSON('url', [data], callback(){})`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: I can't because it causes SyntaxError

Comment: if "json" type doesn't work, you can't do it.

Comment: @SpYk3HH `from another domain`

Comment: @Gothdo: JSON + POST can work if the host supports CORS.

Comment: Yeah, and? He could just mean he's trying to reach a REST. You use "*another domain*" everyday. [`echo json_encode([data]);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) seen all over the world

Comment: Yes, you can only in one case if your URL is in locally in the same server like this `url: '/posts/create'. Other you have to use JSONP, if calling `url: 'example.com/posts/create'`

Comment: @7urkm3n unfortunately it's on another server

Comment: @AlexWasHere then u have to use JSONP otherwise u ll have cross-origin issue. Give us more code issue, to fix it faster.

Comment: @7urkm3n the problem is that the server I call doesn't provide any JSONP data (doesn't wrap JSON in any callback)

Comment: can you post that link and what exactly trying to get after posting your object.